# Изменение текста inline-клавиатуры, python telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Есть ли способ изменить текст в кнопках inline, который был задан раньше? К примеру я задаю текст "Привет" на кнопку b1 и добавляю её в клавиатуру k1 с параметром action1, при выполнении которого текст на кнопке изменяется на "Пока"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, конечно.
Пример:

```
... Ваш код
kbEx = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
exBtn = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Старый", callback_data="test")
kbEx.row(exBtn)
... Ваш код
bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def example(call):
    if call.data == "test":
        exBtn = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Новый", callback_data="hello")
        kbEx.row(exBtn)
```

Примерно так должно выглядить